# after login, redirect to entrance url?

Tags: drupal

The site I'm working on is using the Frontpage module to redirect anon users to a login page.  And I know about using triggers to set an action to redirect after login, (set to one specific url).  But here's the catch:

My users are each arriving at a different entrance url, eg: www.mysite/PersonsName

Is there a way to redirect back to the entrance url after login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to code: this is performed, with various settings available, by the existing [login_destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module.

Comment: Wow!  Very cool, thanks for that FGM!  Looks like what the doctor ordered.

Answer (score 2):

you can put this code in your custom module implementing hook_user().

```
function yourmodule_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = null)
{
  switch ($op) {
    case 'login':
      $_REQUEST['destination'] = $_REQUEST['q'];
    break;
  }
}
```

generally it's enough to set $_REQUEST['destination'] to you desidered destination page
(this is what the module login_destination does i guess)

Answer (score 0):

You can take the URL and explode by "/" like this:

```
$url =  explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Then, set up a session to keep the username he accessed like this:

```
$_SESSION['used_name'] = $url[0];
```

And you can set up the page that he is being redirected to after the succesful login like this:

```
$success_page = "yourpage/".$_SESSION['used_name'];
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks Manny, interesting concept